# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk : how to set the wsgi path?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I practice set up Django under Elastic Beanstalk from there document. 
But There is error.

```
ERROR   Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist.
```

My directory like this:

```
-djangoenv (where I use git)
     - mysite 
          -manage.py
          -mysite 
              -__init__.py 
              -settings.py
              -urls.py
              -wsgi.py
```

and My the `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.djapp` file like this :

[image]

And  `.ebextensions/python.config`   like this , I don't know where to put this .try several times still not work  . I try `mysite/mysite/wsgi.py` still not work

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:    
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: mysite/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: mysite.settings
```

Please tell me how and where to set my wsgi path ??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

I found that you have to restart the server for it to take these changes into consideration.

I spent ages changing and tweaking these options and nothing worked. Then when I went to the EB console and restarted the environment it worked.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case for post 2014 elasticbeanstalk.

Comment: Restart seemed to work for me. I ran `eb console`, then, on the EB dashboard, clicked the _Actions_ drop-down on the top right and chose _Restart App Server(s)_ .  I'm now getting different errors so presumably EB is recognizing the wsgi path in my config file.

Comment: My other error was due to fact that I had not set up a database for the environment. Now the deployment is complete without errors, so the restart definitely did the trick.

Comment: If you're tracking your repository with git, make sure .ebextensions directory is being tracked, and make sure all changes are committed. Otherwise, eb deploy won't pick up the changes and will infer the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

In the server you are about to deploy the django application to elasticbean stalk. Run:

eb config

Then replace the application.py to mysite/wsgi.py and save the changes.

After the update, you may do:

git add.
git commit -m "some updates"
eb deploy

After successfully update the environment, you may view the changes in elasticbeanstalk, under your enviroment, go to the instance and check the setting in **Configuration**, then view the **WSGIPath** under **Software Configuration**.

Disclaimer: This information is valid until 4 November 2016. AWS may further change the setting.

Answer (score 5):

The path specified should be relative to the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory.
The correct path should be `mysite/mysite.wsgi.py`. `option_settings:` is:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: mysite.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You have WSGIPath set to "application.py" but your WSGI file is "mysite/wsgi.py".

Comment: I try  "mysite/wsgi.py" And also use ````eb update```` And it still can't find the path.

Answer (score 0):

You should try
mysite.wsgi:application and make sure you are in the mysite first folder while deploying your application